# How to add a Custom Fields in Woocommerce 3.1

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i've tried many methods to make a custom fields
in woocommerce 3.1 but this code didnt work for me.

can any one help me to figure out how to add a custom fields like this on the link below
http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Custom fields in Product General tab used `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`  action hook

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field', 
            'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'http://',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
        )
    );

}
```

Now For Saving this fields to data based using `woocommerce_process_product_meta`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

}
```

i hop now you understand. it working with WooCommerce 3.1

Comment: and now i have an issue with adding the data in the products columns in admin panel and the front end side.

Comment: @GravityCode please ask new question with more information and screen shot so we help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026358/how-to-show-data-in-custom-added-field-on-the-front-end-in-woocommerce