# Output a custom field value in WooCommerce single product and cart pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product

I need help to add the custom data in the front end of the product just like this:

[image: See Image]

This image is a sample if PD # i just add and i want it to add in the front end of the product:

[image: See image]

Just done adding a the custom field in WooCommerce product pages general setting tab, with the help of: [How to add a Custom Fields in Woocommerce 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024812/how-to-add-a-custom-fields-in-woocommerce-3-1/) thanks @Ankur Bhadania.

Thanks

Comment: Ankur answer is work?

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes it worked already and i just want to add the custom field data on in the front end, see image for more info,

Comment: @VasimVanzara im just using a example image the case is not solve yet. i dont know how to add that PD number in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple products your product `'_pd_number'` custom field in simple product pages before add-to-cart, using **`woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`** action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_cf_before_addtocart_in_single_products', 1, 0 );
function add_cf_before_addtocart_in_single_products()
{
     global $product;

     $pd_number = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_pd_number', true );
     if( !empty( $pd_number ) )
        echo '<div class="pd-number">PD # '. $pd_number .'</div><br>';

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

[image]

This code is tested on WooCommerce version 3+ and works.

---

You can also output your product custom field in the cart items below the name, using **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook this way:

```
// Displaying the product custom field in the Cart items
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_cf_after_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function add_cf_after_cart_item_name( $name_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key )
{
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 )
        $product_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];

     $pd_number = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_pd_number', true );;
     if( !empty( $pd_number ) )
        $name_html .= '<br><span class="pd-number">PD # '.$pd_number .'</span>';

     return $name_html;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce version 3+ and works.

[image]

---

Here the code I have use from he provided link in comments just for testing:

```
// Display Product settings Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_pd_number',
        'label'       => __( 'PD Number', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => 'PD# XXXXXX',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the PD Number of Product', 'woocommerce' )
    ));
}

// Save Product settings Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $pd_number = $_POST['_pd_number'];
    if( !empty( $pd_number ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_pd_number', esc_attr( $pd_number ) );
}
```

Related answer: [Override External Product URL to "Add to Cart" product button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946264/override-external-product-url-to-add-to-cart-product-button/44036965#44036965)

Answer (score 0):

For display custom product meta in signal product page used 2 hook. used any of one as per your requirement.

> 1) display before WooCommerce product meta. used `woocommerce_product_meta_start`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_extra_info' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_extra_info()
{
     global $woocommerce, $post;
     echo "PD # ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );

}
```

> 2) display after WooCommerce product meta. used `woocommerce_product_meta_end`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_extra_info' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_extra_info()
{
     global $woocommerce, $post;
     echo "PD # ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );

}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, still im going to put this in the functions.php on the theme?

Comment: Yes put this in your function.php in theme

Comment: i got blank page. when i add the woocommerce_product_meta_end.

Comment: Cannot redeclare woo_add_custom_general_fields_extra_info() (previously declared in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxxx/functions.php:137) in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxxx/functions.php on line 148

Comment: do not used this both used only one. `woocommerce_product_meta_start` or `woocommerce_product_meta_end`

Comment: Or change function name. same function not re-declare again

Comment: Thank you,and now it shows no error but nothing changes on the front end, the PD number didnt appear. Best regards.

Comment: You need to change `_text_field` with your fields slug.

Comment: Your theme override the WooCommerce template?. if yes then check in theme/themename/woocommerce\single-product\meta.php. in this file used do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' );  or not

Comment: let me check :D

Comment: @AnkurBhadaina yes it override the woommerce template but this code do_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end' ); si already in there in the meta.php. :D

Comment: then this code working file . please add exit in function and check again or share you code what you put in your function file.